# Iterating through IQueryable with foreach results in an out of memory exception

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm iterating through a smallish (~10GB) table with a foreach / IQueryable and LINQ-to-SQL.
Looks something like this:

```
using (var conn = new DbEntities() { CommandTimeout = 600*100})
{
     var dtable = conn.DailyResults.Where(dr => dr.DailyTransactionTypeID == 1);
     foreach (var dailyResult in dtable)
     {
        //Math here, results stored in-memory, but this table is very small. 
        //At the very least compared to stuff I already have in memory. :)
     }
}
```

The Visual Studio debugger throws an out-of memory exception after a short while at the base of the foreach loop. I'm assuming that the rows of dtable are not being flushed. What to do?

Comment: what do you already have stored in memory that is larger than 10GB? Did you mean 10 MB?

Comment: I have 16GB of memory on this machine, but at least half of it is in use by whatever windows bloat plus SQL caches. I couldn't fit 10GB into memory, so I ran out of it. I am suprised that IQueryable retrieves the entire table... I would expect it to fetch one or a small number of rows at a time.

Comment: I seem to have been able to get around this a bit by changing the compile target to x64 instead of x86, which makes use of more of the memory on my machine. However, the data that I'm iterating through in my foreach loop isn't huge, so I think the stuff inside the loop is not getting garbage collected properly.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `IQueryable<DailyResult>` `dtable` will attempt to load the entire query result into memory when enumerated... before any iterations of the foreach loop.  It does not load one row during the iteration of the foreach loop.  If you want that behavior, use [DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=VS.100).aspx).

Comment: By now I have actually exported the table to a flat file, and read it line by line. Next time I'll be using DataReader like a pro. :)

Comment: so why there is error when you iterating through iqueryable(There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first) when you execute another query while looping through the results of the first query ?

Answer (score 10):

You call ~10GB smallish? you have a nice sense of humor!

You might consider loading rows in chunks, aka pagination.

```
conn.DailyResults.Where(dr => dr.DailyTransactionTypeID == 1).Skip(x).Take(y);
```

Comment: Unless the OP has 20 GB of RAM this is the only way to deal with the situation.

Comment: I'm unsure, do you mean to tell me that this pagination method is efficient? I'm just so surprised that IQueriable wants to load stuff into memory. I mean, why not make it an array of some kind to indicate to the helpless programmer about its nasty intensions. :)

Answer (score 4):

Use **.AsNoTracking()** - it tells DbEntities **not to cache** retrieved rows

```
using (var conn = new DbEntities() { CommandTimeout = 600*100})
{
     var dtable = conn.DailyResults
                .AsNoTracking()      // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                .Where(dr => dr.DailyTransactionTypeID == 1);
     foreach (var dailyResult in dtable)
     {
        //Math here, results stored in-memory, but this table is very small. 
        //At the very least compared to stuff I already have in memory. :)
     }
}
```

Comment: That's not what AsNoTracking is mainly intended for. Be aware the result will not be tracked, so you'll to re-attach those row if you want to save modifications.

Answer (score 2):

Using DataReader is a step backward unless there is a way to use it within LINQ.  I thought we were trying to get away from ADO.

The solution suggested above works, but it's truly ugly.  Here is my code:

```
int iTake = 40000;
int iSkip = 0;
int iLoop;
ent.CommandTimeout = 6000;
while (true)
{
  iLoop = 0;
  IQueryable<viewClaimsBInfo> iInfo = (from q in ent.viewClaimsBInfo
                                       where q.WorkDate >= dtStart &&
                                         q.WorkDate <= dtEnd
                                       orderby q.WorkDate
                                       select q)
                                      .Skip(iSkip).Take(iTake);
  foreach (viewClaimsBInfo qInfo in iInfo)
  {
    iLoop++;
    if (lstClerk.Contains(qInfo.Clerk.Substring(0, 3)))
    {
          /// Various processing....
    }
  }
  if (iLoop < iTake)
    break;
  iSkip += iTake;
}
```

You can see that I have to check for having run out of records because the foreach loop will end at 40,000 records.  Not good.

Updated 6/10/2011: Even this does not work.  At 2,000,000 records or so, I get an out-of-memory exception.  It is also excruciatingly slow.  When I modified it to use OleDB, it ran in about 15 seconds (as opposed to 10+ minutes) and didn't run out of memory.  Does anyone have a LINQ solution that works and runs quickly?

Comment: I'm not sure i follow some of the weirder parts, but the idea is => Query, Skip, Take. Fantastic, except for the part where now you get a different problem - how much to take. Also welcome to stackoverflow! :D

Comment: Gleno, thanks.  I'm not sure what you consider the "weirder parts," although "weird" seems to be my middle name. :)  I went back to ADO.Net, unfortunately, as noted.

Comment: I know this is very old, but since it still came right up on Google search...for the memory / performance, you probably need to use `.AsNoTracking()`, as parfilko suggested in their answer. And as for cleaning up the code, you could make an extension method to handle the batching logic. Something like `IEnumerable<T> InBatches<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, int batchSize)`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using SQL instead to modify this data.