# Code Coming up blank every time

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this code and it is supposed to fill up the appropriate tables and it is filling the first table (`Mu_Reports`) one but the second table (`MU_By_Machine`) keeps coming up blank

```
using (var db = new ProductionContext())
        {
            var objct = ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
            objct.ExecuteStoreCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [MU Report]");
            objct.ExecuteStoreCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [MU By Machine]");
            db.SaveChanges();

            var query = db.Production_Reports
                .GroupBy(x => new { x.Date, x.Machine_Number, x.Shift })
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    Date = x.Key.Date,
                    Shift = x.Key.Shift,
                    MachineNum = x.Key.Machine_Number,
                    MU = x.Sum(i => i.Partial_MU_ * 100)
                }).ToList();

            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                var z = new MU_Report();

                z.Date = System.Convert.ToDateTime(item.Date);
                z.Shift = item.Shift;
                z.Machine_Number = item.MachineNum;
                z.MU = item.MU;

                db.MU_Reports.Add(z);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            var query2 = from b in db.MU_Reports
                         join downtime in db.Downtime_Reports on b.Shift equals downtime.Shift
                         where downtime.Downtime_Code.Equals("9185")
                         group downtime by new { b.Date, b.Shift, b.Machine_Number, b.MU } into g
                         select new
                         {
                             Date = g.Key.Date,
                             Shift = g.Key.Shift,
                             Machine = g.Key.Machine_Number,
                             MU = g.Key.MU,
                             No_Work_Hours = g.Sum(x => x.Total_DownTime)
                         };
            foreach (var item in query2)
            {
                var y = new MU_By_Machine();

                y.Date = item.Date;
                y.Shift = item.Shift;
                y.Machine_Number = item.Machine;
                y.MU = item.MU;
                y.MU_w_o_No_Work = (item.MU * 8) / (8 - item.No_Work_Hours);

                db.MU_By_Machines.Add(y);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

I don't know if it is because I cannot have `query` and `query2` go in the same button or if I am just doing something wrong. No error occurs only `MU_By_Machine` appears blank. Please keep in mind I'm new to C#.

Comment: I have done this by breaking the 2 queries down into separate methods and then invoking them when the button is pressed. Then I am able to use debug point to see if you are getting data back to the foreach statement in query2 or if you're broke elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to invoke `.ToList()` at the end of your select statement in `query2` as well.

Comment: I think it's [possible](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3688213/188246) to return data from an `IQueryable` in a `foreach` without calling `ToList()`. The error is probably elsewhere.

Comment: even without the ToList() there should be something returned to the foreach loop, but most likely only the last item in the query results.

Comment: How do I add the `.ToList()` on this one? Do I have to translate it if so I've tried and failed miserably to do that